# Python Contour Plot with 1D slices on the side

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a contour map (using `contourf`), but I also want to show on the sides a slice of the plot through particular points, such as the figure shown below.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot you show is produced via a [seaborn `jointplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html).

[This example](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/joint_kde.html) shows how to produce the this kind of plot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Generate a random correlated bivariate dataset
rs = np.random.RandomState(5)
mean = [0, 0]
cov = [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
x1, x2 = rs.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 500).T
x1 = pd.Series(x1, name="$X_1$")
x2 = pd.Series(x2, name="$X_2$")

# Show the joint distribution using kernel density estimation
g = sns.jointplot(x1, x2, kind="kde", size=7, space=0)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

[image]